# When should connect components to redux in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

For example, i have a structure of components like this:

```
<Parent>
      <Child_1>
            <InnerChild_1 />
      </Chidl_1>
      <Child_2>
            <InnerChild_2 />
      </Chidl_2>
</Parent>
```

Component `<Parent>` connected to redux. What a better way to update `<InnerChild_1 />` with application state, send this data from `<Parent>` with `props`  or connect `<InnerChild_1 />` to redux ? If connect, should i connect all my components, that's using state, to redux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Despite every other answer stating that you should `connect` your top level, that's indeed an old recommendation that is only useful for very simple applications.

Use `connect` wherever you need to keep a component synchronized with the Redux store. In your example, if `<Parent />` is not using any state and its role is merely compositional, I wouldn't connect that one. I would keep Parent a standard React component, and connect the child items individually.

For big lists or complex data structures with nested entitites, that's the way to go.

If you choose the other way, and connect at your top-most component, then **any** state change will cause a full re-render of your component tree, with no automatic optimization. Because `connect`ed components will implement `shouldComponentUpdate` for you, you'll normally get much better performance connecting multiple items to the store instead of connecting a "list" parent and re-render every item on every change.

See the React-Redux FAQ in the Redux docs:
http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-multiple-components

Specifically:

> Early Redux documentation advised that you should only have a few
>   connected components near the top of your component tree. However,
>   time and experience has shown that that generally requires a few
>   components to know too much about the data requirements of all their
>   descendants, and forces them to pass down a confusing number of props.

Comment: I cannot agree with this. If you dig into the source of React dom renderer, you will find that the performance penalty paid for diffing a DOM element against props that have not changed is minimal. sCU is dangerous in the wrong hands and the cause of many mysterious bugs in my experience because of the difficulty in determining where in the tree it was called.

Comment: I've been working with react-redux for about 2 years now. I've been using the smart vs dump components approach where only a "smart" container component would connect to store changes and pass down state as properties. My conclusion is that this pattern is obsolete and harmful in several ways: 1. it introduces heavy nested component dependencies across the component tree 2. it affects performance by determining the entire tree to re-render on state change 3. Turns code into spaghetti when passing down the tree chain numerous properties which intermediary components have no need o.

Comment: [Should I only connect my top component, or can I connect multiple components in my tree?](https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#should-i-only-connect-my-top-component-or-can-i-connect-multiple-components-in-my-tree)

Answer (score 2):

You should always try to use as little redux in your application as possible, in my experience. As a rule of thumb, always opt for passing props down the component chain as opposed to dispatching actions in child components. To me, redux truly shines when you need to share state across multiple container components. A typical use case is authentication/user data in an e-commerce app. In your situation, I can safely say `connect`ing your child component would simply result in unnecessary indirection.

Comment: 100% agree; read up on "smart" vs "dumb" components; here's one (of many) posts: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.ib885dqmd

Answer (score 1):

IMHO better use `connect` for `Containers` rather than for `Components`.

`Container` holds the Components. So `connect` the `redux` state to `Container` which in turn sends the state to `Components` as `props`.

In your case you can assume  `<Parent />` as `Container` and rest of children as Components.

Comment: If i have a lot of nestings, and need to re-render last component, and if i send props from container all my components "on a way" will be re-rendered. Is it normal?

Comment: The performance penalty in this regard is quite minimal. It's a fair trade off to make for reduced complexity in your application overall. Yes, components further up the tree will get re-rendered, but since there won't be many DOM mutations on those, it won't matter very much. If you really need to stop re-rendering midway through a tree, you can always reach for `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use either a spread operator (...props) or context.

Via spread would look like this:

```
<InnerChild_1 
    {...this.props}
/>
```

Comment: This is another way of sending props. I want to know, what's better, send props or connect to redux.

Comment: The best practice is to keep redux as in the top components as possible and send props down.

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/faq/OrganizingState.md